# python - authorise to continue on return press

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to write a function in tkinter which will run until the user gives the correct password. In principle, it should be the same as:

```
check = input('type ok')
while True:
    if check == 'ok'
        break
    else:
        check = input('type ok')
print('You made it!')
```

...but with a few frustrating differences:
1. I'm not using the input() function, but rather getting text from a tkinter Text widget.
2. This check method is bound to a return press, which just generally makes things very inconvenient
The best I have, so far (in pseudo-code ish):

```
def authenticate():
    root.bind('<Return>', check)
    if auth == True:
        return
    else:
        root.after(500, authenticate)

def check():
    if pword == correct_pword:
        auth = True

def signin():
    auth = False
    authenticate()
    print('you're signed in!')
```

This way, `authenticate` only returns when the user presses enter and the password is correct. I thought that meant that the code in signin would only continue then, but this doesn't seem to be the case for whatever reason.
Is this the right approach? I don't understand why the code continues before the function has returned anything.

Comment: Sequential code, with user interaction in the middle, is not generally a workable approach in a GUI.  You need to think in terms of events being handled, instead.  All your program will do at first is just bind <Return> to a function, no more; the process continues in that function, which will display an error (or simply exit) if the password is wrong, otherwise it does whatever is appropriate to being authenticated (probably starting with hiding the password field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like jasonharper said in his comment, you should not think the same way as for a command line program. Especially, you don't need a while loop since the mainloop of the GUI provides one already (the GUI waits for events like keyboard input, mouse click, ...).

So you just need to create the entry for the password and bind the Return key to a function that checks whether the password is right or not. Each time the user presses "Return", the function will be called and for instance destroy the login window if the password is right or clear the entry if it's wrong.

Corresponding code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def login(event):
    pwd = entry.get()
    if pwd == "ok":
        print("You are logged in !")
        root.destroy()
    else:
        entry.delete(0, "end")

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root, show="*")
entry.pack()

entry.bind("<Key-Return>", login)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of this method, but was wary of using it, as, in my case, the user has to 'approve' things by password, and a lot of code would have to be inside of login (in place of just printing something). But if this is the only thing that will work, I can use it

Comment: If there is a lot of code to put in login, you could split it in several functions called inside the login function.